# Hammer.js Touch gestures on cheap android tablet not working

Tags: android, hammer.js

I just bought a 7" android 4.0 tablet (Arnova 7F G3) and i'm trying to run a couple of demos to test the touch gestures. Thing is... nothing's happening when I touch the screen, whereas on the iPad, it works a treat! Really smooth!

The demo i'm looking at is: http://riagora.com/mobile/hammer/

As I said, it's perfect on the iPad and also in firefox on my desktop. Just wondering if the tablet is just rubbish? That said it's really quick for most other things

Anybody have an idea what's going on?

Cheers!
D

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out , jcw! Will do! The most recent question that I posted, there was multiple right answers, but from what I can see only one answer can be clicked as being correct! Am I missing something?

Comment: In that case you are simply meant to select the most in depth answer. If they are all identical, just pick the first answer or the that you used.

Answer (score 0):

quick update! I've just downloaded the latest version of Firefox for Android and all the gesture events seem to be working. Still no luck with the default stock android 4.0.2 browser which is very disappointing! Also Dolphin, which I had high hopes for is a dead duck!

But at least I know its not the tablet that sux! In fact it is very smooth and quick! Kudos to Arnova!

Cheers!
Dec